# Persist an entity after another entity ~ Netbeans, J2E, bean, EntityManager

Tags: java, javabeans, entitymanager, persist, j2ep

I'm doing a project of software engineering with Java EE, Glassfish and Netbeans and I have a problem due to lack of java experience.

I'm developing a website that offers to users the possibility to create some events.

I was able to save in a table `event` the information about the events (ID, name, place, date, creator) and now the problem is to populate another table `calendar`. In this table there are only 3 attributes: an ID (generated automatically and sequentially), the creator e-mail and the event ID. The aim of this `calendar` table is to collect all the couple user-event: an event can be coupled not only to its creator but also to other users that are invited.

When I try to make persistent the data in the `calendar` table a I get a `NullPointerException` because in the `event` table the ID is generated automatically and i think that when i call the `getEventID` method, this value is still `null`.

How can I activate a `CalendarManager` that has simply to take the *creator* and the *ID* of the event and write them in the `calendar` table?

I hope that I was clear, here there are some files:

The `EventManager` works fine:

```java
@Stateless
public class EventManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    Principal principal;

    public void saveEvent(Event event) {
        em.persist(event);
    }

    public void deleteEvent(Event event) {
        em.remove(event);
    }

}
```

The `CalendarEventsManager` is fine but doesn't receive the correct parameters:

```java
@Stateless
public class CalendarEventsManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager cm;

    @Inject
    Principal principal;

    public void saveCalendarEvents(CalendarEvents calendarevents) {
        cm.persist(calendarevents);     
    }

    public void deleteCalendarEvents(CalendarEvents calendarevents) {
        cm.remove(calendarevents);
    }
}
```

Below there is the **CRITICAL PART** in the Bean that is activated when a user click on "Create Event":

```java
public String saveEvent() {
    /* obtain the creator's email */
    creator = um.getLoggedUser().getEmail();
    this.event.setCreator(creator);

    /* save information in db event */
    em.saveEvent(event);

    /* save information in db calendar */

    eventid = event.getID();
    this.calendarevents.setUserEmail(creator);
    this.calendarevents.setEventID(eventid);
    cm.saveCalendarEvents(calendarevents);

    /* next page to visualize */
    return "displayEvent";
}
```

Until `em.saveEvent(event)` everything is fine and the database is correctly updated, but the problem is that when I do `eventid = getID()` (`getID` is public in the `Event` class and is correct). The system isn't able to read the ID because it doesn't read from the database just updated.

Here there is the Event class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Integer id;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String name;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String place;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String eventdate;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String type;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String visibility;
/*@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String weather;*/
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String creator;

public void setID(Integer id){
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setName(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public String getDate() {
    return eventdate;
}

public void setDate(String eventdate) {
    this.eventdate = eventdate;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getVisibility() {
    return visibility;
}

public void setVisibility(String visibility) {
    this.visibility = visibility;
}

/*public String getWeather() {
    return weather;
}

public void setWeather(String weather) {
    this.weather = weather;
}*/

public String getCreator() {
    return creator;
}

public void setCreator(String creator) {
    this.creator = creator;
}
```

Do you have some ideas to resolve this problem? I've read about the `@PostPersist` annotation but i don't how to apply it correctly :(

Thanks in advice to all who will try to help me :D

**EDIT1**: 
The error is probably in this code in saveEvent():

```
    this.calendarevents.setUserEmail(creator);
    this.calendarevents.setEventId(eventid);
    System.out.println("event id after get is:   " + this.calendarevents.getUserEmail());
    System.out.println("event id after get is:   " + this.calendarevents.getEventId());
    cm.saveCalendarEvents(calendarevents);
```

I've put the system.out.println to verify the value but the error is in the "this.calendarevents" because there no signs of the system.out ! Here there is the complete Bean!

```
@Named(value = "createBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CreateEventBean {

@EJB
private EventManager em;
@EJB
private UserManager um;

private Event event;
private String creator;

@EJB
private CalendarEventsManager cm;

private Integer eventid=0;
private CalendarEvents calendarevents;

public CreateEventBean() {
}

public Event getEvent() {
    if (event == null){
        event = new Event();
    }
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;

}

public CalendarEvents getCalendarEvent() {
    if (calendarevents == null){
        calendarevents = new CalendarEvents();
    }
    return calendarevents;
}

public void setCalendarEvents(CalendarEvents calendarevents) {
    this.calendarevents = calendarevents;

}

public String saveEvent(){
    /*obtain the creator's email*/
    creator=um.getLoggedUser().getEmail();
    this.event.setCreator(creator);

    /*save information in db event*/
    em.saveEvent(event);

    /*save information in db calendar*/
    System.out.println("event id before get is:   " + eventid);
    eventid=event.getId();
    System.out.println("event id after get is:   " + eventid);

    this.calendarevents.setEventId(eventid);
    System.out.println("eventid in calendar could be:   " + this.calendarevents.getEventId());
    this.calendarevents.setUserEmail(creator);
    System.out.println("useremail in calendar could be:   " + this.calendarevents.getUserEmail());

    cm.saveCalendarEvents(calendarevents);



    /*next page to visualize*/
    return "displayEvent";
}

}
```

I really don't catch the error in "this.calendarevents.setEventId(eventid);" that is line 80 and the error is this: Caused by: Warning:   #{createBean.saveEvent()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{createBean.saveEvent()}: java.lang.NullPointerException    [Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at it.nyquistmeteocal.beans.CreateEventBean.saveEvent(CreateEventBean.java:80)]

Here is the CalendarEvents Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="calendarevents")
public class CalendarEvents implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Integer id;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private String useremail;
@NotNull(message = "May not be empty")
private Integer eventid;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setName(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return useremail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String useremail) {
    this.useremail = useremail;
}


public Integer getEventId() {
    return eventid;
}

public void setEventId(Integer eventid) {
    this.eventid = eventid;
}


}
```

Comment: please post your event class

Comment: try to rename the `getID` to `getId` and `setID` to `setId`

Comment: unfortunately the same problem:
Warning:   #{createBean.saveEvent()}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{createBean.saveEvent()}: java.lang.NullPointerException

The "event" table is updated but then nothing happens to the "calendarevents" (previously i've described it as "calendar")


Maybe there is another way to: Insert information in "event" table; extract creator and eventid and save them in "calendarevents" table ? (For invited users i will think later about insert also them email and couple with the eventid)

Comment: actually, if you confirmed that the event is been saved in the DB and it has one id generated.. the entity should have its value after persisted

Comment: I've test the situation system.out like this: System.out.println("event id before get is:   " + eventid);
        eventid=event.getId();
        System.out.println("event id after get is:   " + eventid);   the results is that before is 0 (i initialized eventid to 0) and after is 16, that is the correct id of the event!! I've updated the post with more information about the problem :)

Comment: sorry.. it is really confusing, first you said that the event.getID wasn't reading from the DB, now you said that the problem is with the calendarevents, review your persistence EJB and calendarevent classes

Comment: Probably i wasn't able to describe the situation in the right way due to some wrong personal assumptions. I thought that the NullPointerException was because the eventid is generated automatically, while the problem was with calendarevents that remained always to null.   I really appreciate your help because you have assured me some important things about the situation! Have a good time :)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem!!

I've simply modified the declaration of calendarevents in this way:

```
private CalendarEvents calendarevents = new CalendarEvents();
```

I didn't do it before i think that if calendarevents points to NULL it will be executed this part of the code:

```
public CalendarEvents getCalendarEvent() {
    if (this.calendarevents == null){
        this.calendarevents = new CalendarEvents();
    }
    return this.calendarevents;
}

public void setCalendarEvents(CalendarEvents calendarevents) {
    calendarevents = calendarevents;

}
```

Does it mean that I don't need this last part? :)

Comment: It means that instead of `this.calendarevents.setEventId(eventid);` you should have used `this.getCalendarEvents().setEventId(eventid);` :)